# ImageView exibe a imagem girada em 90 graus

Tags: android, imagem, download

Quando faço o Upload de uma foto para o servidor e vou exibi-la utilizando

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Caminhofoto).into(fotoalerta);
```

Se a foto foi tirada com o celular na vertical ela é carregada no horizontal teria como exibir ela corretamente. Tenho esse mesmo problema quando carregar ela do SDCARD mais estou utilizando esse código para exibir corretamente.

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}



public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation) {

    try{
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Minha class de UPLOAD da imagem

```
public class classe_FTP
{
    FTPClient mFtp;
    private String TAG = "classeFTP";

public boolean MudarDiretorio(String Diretorio)
{
    try
    {
        mFtp.changeWorkingDirectory(Diretorio);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível mudar o diretório para " + Diretorio);
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean Desconectar()
{
    try
    {
        mFtp.disconnect();
        mFtp = null;
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: ao desconectar. " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean Conectar(String Host, String Usuario, String Senha, int Porta)
{
    try
    {
        mFtp = new FTPClient();

        mFtp.connect(Host, Porta);

        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFtp.getReplyCode()))
        {
            boolean status = mFtp.login(Usuario, Senha);

            mFtp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFtp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: não foi possível conectar" + Host);
    }
    return false;
}



public boolean Upload(String diretorio, String nomeArquivo)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream arqEnviar = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + diretorio);
        mFtp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
        mFtp.setFileType(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
        mFtp.storeFile("/patrulhar.com.br/imagens/"+nomeArquivo, arqEnviar);
        Desconectar();
        System.out.println("Upload win1 . ");
        return status;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: Falha ao efetuar Upload1. " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return status;
}

public boolean Upload2(String diretorio, String nomeArquivo)
{
    boolean status = false;
    try
    {
        FileInputStream arqEnviar = new FileInputStream(diretorio);
        mFtp.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
        mFtp.setFileType(FTPClient.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
        mFtp.storeFile("/patrulhar.com.br/imagens/"+nomeArquivo, arqEnviar);
        Desconectar();
        System.out.println("Upload win2 . ");
        return status;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "Erro: Falha ao efetuar Upload2. " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return status;
}
}
```

Comment: Se entendi bem então a solução passa por usar o método `rotateBitmap()` nessa situação também.

Comment: Mais tem como eu utilizar o rotateBitmap() utilizando o picasso ou como eu deveria fazer isso ?

Comment: Faça o *rotate* da imagem antes do *upload*

Comment: Faço o upload da imagem pelo caminho dela no celular como eu poderia fazer utilizando esse bitmap com ela certa?

Answer (score 0):

Através da API Picasso é possível aceder ao *Bitmap* após o *load* recorrendo ao método [transform()](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#transform-com.squareup.picasso.Transformation-) do [RequestCreator](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html).

Crie uma classe que implemente a interface [Transformation](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Transformation.html):

```
public class ImageTransformation implements Transformation {
    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {

        //Faça aqui o que quiser com o bitmap e retorne-o.
    }

    @Override public String key() { return "square()"; }
}
```

Utilize desta forma:

```
ImageTransformation imageTransformation = new ImageTransformation();
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(Caminhofoto)
       .transform(imageTransformation)
       .into(fotoalerta);
```

No entanto, como o pretendido é apenas rodar a imagem, o [RequestCreator](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html) disponibiliza o método [rotate()](http://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#rotate-float-) para esse efeito:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(Caminhofoto)
       .rotate(degrees)
       .into(fotoalerta);
```

ou

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
       .load(Caminhofoto)
       .rotate(degrees, pivotX, pivotY)
       .into(fotoalerta);
```